# Box plot using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, boxplot

Trying to plot a box plot for a pandas dataframe but the x-axis column names don't appear to be clear.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
pd.set_option('display.mpl_style', 'default')
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
%matplotlib inline
df.boxplot(column = ['avg_dist','avg_rating_by_driver','avg_rating_of_driver','avg_surge','surge_pct','trips_in_first_30_days','weekday_pct'])
```

Below is the output

[image]

How to fix this so that the x-axis columns appear clear

Comment: maybe parameter `rot` can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need parameter `rot`:

```
cols = ['avg_dist','avg_rating_by_driver','avg_rating_of_driver',
        'avg_surge','surge_pct','trips_in_first_30_days','weekday_pct']

df.boxplot(column=cols, rot=90)
```

Sample:

```
np.random.seed(100)
cols = ['avg_dist','avg_rating_by_driver','avg_rating_of_driver',
        'avg_surge','surge_pct','trips_in_first_30_days','weekday_pct']
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 7), columns=cols)
df.boxplot(column=cols, rot=90)
```

[image: graph]

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to make the orientation of you boxes horizontal.

```
np.random.seed(100)
cols = ['avg_dist','avg_rating_by_driver','avg_rating_of_driver',
        'avg_surge','surge_pct','trips_in_first_30_days','weekday_pct']
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 7), columns=cols)
df.boxplot(column=cols, vert=False)
```

[image]